# group lines in a csv when reading

Tags: python, csv

I have a report in a csv format that has a section of grouped data.

that is, at a certain point, i want to deal with the data from 2 rows at a time

```
0. headers,,,,
1. regular data,,,,
2. regular data,,,,
3. batched_data_a, 0,1,2,3
4. batched_data_a, 4,5,6,7
5. batched_data_b, 0,1,2,3
6. batched_data_b, 4,5,6,7
7. batched_data_c, 0,1,2,3
8. batched_data_c, 4,5,6,7
```

i'm wondering if anyone has a strategy.

right now, all i can think of is using `for idx, row in enumerate( csvreader ):` , and using the idx to correlate data.  wondering if anyone has another suggestion.

Comment: It would be best to use generator for this. How would you like to have those rows provided? as a tuple, joined?

Comment: oh, great idea.  this looks like a promising read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019573/pythons-csv-reader-and-iteration

Comment: Good luck, and remember to post your answer when you figure it out! ;)

Comment: the data isn't exactly like the above.. but i need to generate a tuple that contains the column values for each of the 'groups'.  for example, lines 3,4 would generate (0,4), (1,5), (2,6), (3,7).  i'll try to play with some generator ideas tomorrow.   i keep forgetting about them!

Comment: thanks.  generators were exactly what I needed.  i posted the answer. I ended up writing a class to wrap the csv file, and created separate generators as properties -- one to handle the header, the other to handle the body.

Comment: for these types of things, assuming it's not a ton of data, i just process it with pandas. it's just a lot more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv

cr = csv.reader(file("test.csv"))
while True:
    try:
        row1, row2 = cr.next(), cr.next()
        row = [row1[0]] + row1[1:] + row2[1:]
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print row
```

Comment: Not entirely, but almost.  I need to iterate over 2 different sections differently, and that handles only the second type.... but perfectly. The row combination you shared is excellent , and will be refactored into the solution I went with.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a custom class to wrap the file, and used generators (like https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388392/m-wasowski suggested ) to handle each section.

I could/should probably use the row combination that https://stackoverflow.com/users/408426/rumple-stiltskin suggested ( that's a great idea ), but I've already got the consumer written.  I flagged that answer in the source-code for when there's time to rewrite!

```
class CustomFile(object):

    def __init__(self, csvdata):   
        self.csvdata = csvdata

    @property
    def header( self ):
        reader = csv.reader( self.csvdata[0:3] )
        for row in reader:
            yield row

    @property
    def body( self ):
        reader = csv.reader( self.csvdata[3:] )
        for l1 in reader :
            if not any(l1):
                raise StopIteration()
            l2 = reader.next()
            yield l1, l2



csvdata = open('data.csv', 'r').readlines()
csvdata = [i.strip() for i in csvdata ]

customFile = CustomFile( csvdata )
print [ i for i in customFile.header ]
print [ i for i in customFile.body ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first column in the real data is actually matching, e.g. if 'batched_data_a' follows 'batched_data_a', then they go together, you can split the file into a list of lines, split the lines into lists of words, and then iterate through using indices.

What I mean is something like

```
lines = file_name.splitlines()
split_lines = []
for lin in lines:
    split_lines.append(lin.split(","))
```

That leaves you with an list of lists: Each line is a now a list of comma separated values, and the whole file is a list of lines. Then you can iterate through to get the tuples you want by checking if adjacent lines match.

```
tuple_list = []
for i in range(0, len(split_lines) - 1):
    this_line = split_lines[i]
    next_line = split_lines[i+1]
    if this_line[0] == next_line[0]:
        k = 1
        while k < 5:
            a = this_line[k]
            b = next_line[k]
            tuple_list.append((this_line[0], a, b))
            k += 1
```

It's not the fastest way to do it, but without me being able to test it on your data set, I think a simple solution is good.